# Opencart 2.0.1.1 vQmod download and Installation

Tags: e-commerce, opencart2.x, vqmod

I have downloaded vQmod from `https://github.com/vqmod/vqmod/releases`
When I installed the files in opencart root folder and run opencart website

```
http://localhost/opencart/vqmod/install/
```

i should see the installation success message,but i am unable to use vQmod properly,please tell me what is the proper way of installing vQmod in OpenCart 2.0.1.1 ?

Comment: Solved ! I have followed this link 
https://github.com/vqmod/vqmod/wiki/Installing-vQmod-on-OpenCart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have followed this link
 `github.com/vqmod/vqmod/wiki/Installing-vQmod-on-OpenCart`
It provided me the proper way of installing vQmod in opencart